# self redirecting script instead of a cron job

Tags: php, cron

i have problems setting up a cron job that runs every few seconds. 
i came up with an idea to instead of running my script with a cron job, make it simply redirect to the same page after x seconds.
i would then open the page once and my server will keep reloading itself.

```
<?php 

//do stuff you want repeated

sleep(2);

header("Location: autoreload.php"); 
//echo "hello";
exit();
?>
```

i tested it by sending an email to myself from the script and it works.
is this bad practice and why?

Answer (score 0):

use `refresh` header

```php
<?php
header( "refresh:5" );

//do stuff you want repeated

echo 'this page will be reloaded in 5 seconds';

exit();
?>
```

Remember that `header()` must be called before any actual output is sent

Comment: so it's okay to do this?